# C# Fake Class Formas de utilización

Tags: c#

Soy nuevo en probar la funcionalidad de fake class de [.net](/questions/tagged/.net) y tengo las siguientes preguntas:
​

1. Siempre se debe ejecutar el código de prueba dentro de:

   ```
   using (ShimsContext.Create() {
       // Código de prueba
   }
   ```

   ​para que funcione los dummys de las pruebas unitarias.
2. Los stub solo sirven para interfaces en que otros casos los puedo 
   utilizar.

Comment: ¿Ya checaste esta info https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-MX/library/hh549176.aspx?

Comment: @AlejandroSoler te ha servido la respuesta?

Answer (score 1):

Entiendo que te refieres a los stubs y shims generados mediante Microsoft Fakes (existen otras formas de crear fakes, mocks o stubs, sea en .Net u otros lenguajes).

Respondiendo a tu primer pregunta (1), si, pues se quiere mantener el contexto de ejecución del shim acotado.

Es decir, cuando se crea, usa y destruye el shim. Si no fuera así, el shim viviría dentro del contexto de todas las pruebas (es decir, las afectaría todas). Para más detalles de como utilizar los shims ver el siguiente [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/hh549176.aspx). Dejo el lnik en inglés porque la traducción automática es muy mala.

Sobre tu otra pregunta (2), si, los stubs sólo sirven para implementar facilmente interfaces a fin de utilizarlos dentro tus pruebas. Para más detalle de que es un stub, ver el siguiente [link](https://itblogsogeti.com/2015/03/26/desarrollo-pruebas-unitarias-trinitario-gomez-sogeti/).